# iPad take a shot with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, ipad, camera

I 'm trying to take a shot and it works, but with 2 problems. First, the pop over controller is displayed in a minimum size (it doesn't obey the setPopoverContentSize) and second and most important, the captured shot is only 640x640 pixels, whereas I want to be the maximum available (5MP).

What's the problem in the following code?

```
imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imgPicker.delegate = self;
imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imgPicker.showsCameraControls = YES;

pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imgPicker];
pop.delegate = self;
CGRect re = CGRectMake(50,20,100,20);
CGRect re2 = CGRectMake(0,0,500,500);
[pop setPopoverContentSize:re2.size];
[pop presentPopoverFromRect:re inView:[self view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny  animated:YES];
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the content size incorrectly. You don't call `setPopoverContentSize:` on the popover, you call it on the view controller that is displayed in the popover. In your case, set the content size of the image picker.

The image received from the image picker is the full sized image. Perhaps you are obtaining the edited image instead of the original image.